# How to send events in Adobe Analytics using GTM

Tags: analytics, google-tag-manager, adobe-analytics

I am using GTM to fire Adobe Analytics scripts on all the pages. It is working as desired. However I am wondering if is there a way to set up click events with no page refresh, in the same way as Google Analytics click events are set up. I am using s.tl() call however it is not sending the events to adobe omniture. Any thoughts on this. I know if I use DTM, it can be setup easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have Adobe Analytics already present on your website, `s` object is already present on your website.  All you need to do is to put these codes on your website and fire this using GTM as a custom HTML Tag on basis of the trigger you require.  There are standard events like `gtm.js`, `gtm.dom` and `gtm.load` already present.  You can create your own custom event on top of this on basis of elements load.  Using the same event you can fire these lines of codes on your website and this should give you what are you looking for.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var s = s_gi('yourreportsuiteID'); // replace this with your RSID!

    s.visitorNamespace = "yournamespace" //optional
    s.trackingServer = "yourtrackingserver" //optional
    s.trackingServerSecure = "yoursecuretrackingserver"//optional
    s.events = "event35";// your event number has to be activated in Adobe
    s.linkTrackVars = "events,eVar38";//your eVar number has to be activated in Adobe
    s.linkTrackEvents = "event35";
    s.eVar38 = {{GTMVariable}}
    s.tl( this,
          "o",
          "FriendlyName" );
</script>
```

Comment: Several of your lines are not terminated with a `;`.  Forgive me if this seems like a rookie question, but is that supposed to be the case?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing specific to Adobe Analytics to consider - GTM has a built-in click event handler. Go to "triggers", "new", select "click" from the options and optionally specify filters (e.g. if you want the trigger to fire only on certain pages, or only when the link has a specific class).

Assign the trigger to a custom HTML tag with your Adobe Code, save, publish and you are all set.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Pardon my ignorance if I ask something more to this. While GTM has an inbuilt click listener, it can send  click events without page refresh to GA with the event tag. How does it send these events to Adobe Analytics. As adobe analytics would have fired by that time with on pageview trigger(gtm.js). While with DTM it would be easy, was wondering if it could work with GTM as well.